# xhtmlrenderer xhtml to pdf font problem

Tags: java, html, pdf, fonts, xhtmlrenderer

I'm using `org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer` to convert my (x)html page to pdf using Java.

I've got most of it working, except the font part.

I'm using `verdana` in my page and the pdf is rendered using default font.

I have added the verdana.ttf to my jar and use the following code:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(html));      

File tmpFontFile = new File(TEMP_FOLDER + "/verdana.ttf");
      if(!tmpFontFile.exists())
      {
       tmpFontFile.createNewFile();

       InputStream fontIs = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/util/font/verdana.ttf");   
       OutputStream fontOs = new FileOutputStream(tmpFontFile);

       byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
       int len;

       while((len = fontIs.read(buf)) > 0)
        fontOs.write(buf,0,len);

       fontOs.close();
       fontIs.close();
      }


      ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
      renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(
        tmpFontFile.getAbsolutePath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H ,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
      renderer.setDocument(doc, null);

      String outputFile = TEMP_FOLDER + "/mypdf.pdf";
      OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
      renderer.layout();
      renderer.createPDF(os);
      os.close();
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `xhtmlrenderer` to work, the CSS must read:

`font-family: Verdana;`

instead of

`font-family:verdana;`

It's case-sensitive.

Comment: you say `font:family` but i think you mean `font-family`, right?

Comment: font:type will not work might B.T. had used font-family for this :)